# VB .NET How to copy a directory without its subfolders

Tags: vb.net, file, directory, copy, subdirectory

I want t copy all files in a directory, but ignore all sub-folders. Is there a single function to do this?

The standard function:
`My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(inputDir.FullName, outputDir.FullName)`

copies all the sub-folders.

Iterating over all files:

```
For Each file In inputDir.GetFiles()
    file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(outputDir.FullName, file.Name), True)
Next
```

seems to work fine. But it looks too complex to me. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Looks fine to me? `CopyDirectory()` does not provide an overload to not copy sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

Make it into a function ...

```
Public Sub CopyFiles(inputPath As System.IO.DirectoryInfo,
                     outputPath As System.IO.DirectoryInfo)
    For Each fi In inputPath.GetFiles()
        fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(outputPath.FullName, fi.Name), True)
    Next
End Sub
```

... so it can *simply* be called like this when you want to use it

```
CopyFiles(New DirectoryInfo("C:\test1"), New DirectoryInfo("C:\test2"))
```